# ImportError at articles/api/article: Cannot import name ArticleResource

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to create a Django website and every time I run the /articles/api/article page on my local host: I get this traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/articles/api/article

Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'article',
 'tastypie')

Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  87.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  72.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  619.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  494.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/deanna/django-deanna/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/deanna/django_test/django_test/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from tastypie.api import ArticleResource

Exception Type: ImportError at /articles/api/article
Exception Value: cannot import name ArticleResource
```

This my urls.py file, which is located under the django_test/django_test directory:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from tastypie.api import ArticleResource

article_resource = ArticleResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django_test.views.login'),
                   url(r'^accounts/auth/$', 'django_test.views.auth_view'),
                   url(r'^accounts/loggedin/$', 'django_test.views.loggedin'),
                   url(r'^accounts/invalid/$', 'django_test.views.invalid_login'),
                   url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django_test.views.logout'),
                   url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'django_test.views.register_user'),
                   url(r'^accounts/register_success/$', 'django_test.views.register_success'),
                   url(r'^articles/all/$', 'article.views.articles'),
                   url(r'^articles/create/$', 'article.views.create'),
                   url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.article'),
                   url(r'^articles/like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.like_article'),
                   url(r'^articles/add_comment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', 'article.views.add_comment'),
                   url(r'^articles/search/', 'article.views.search_titles'),
                   url(r'^articles/api/article', include(article_resource.urls)),

)
```

This is my api.py file, which is also located in the django_test/django_test directory:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.constants import ALL
from models import Article 

class ArticleResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Article.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'article'
```

I tried separating the third import statement in the api.py file and putting it in a separate file but I still got the same error, so that's not the problem. I synced the db and did all the needed migrations but I still ran into the same error. The TastyPie version I am using is 0.12.1.

I'd appreciate any help I can get, as I have been stuck on this error for literally days now. Thank you.

Edit: I made some changes and now I have a "page not found at /articles/api/article" message even though I have that in my urls.py file. Here is the traceback:

```
Using the URLconf defined in django_test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^admin/
2. ^accounts/login/$
3. ^accounts/auth/$
4. ^accounts/loggedin/$
5. ^accounts/invalid/$
6. ^accounts/logout/$
7. ^accounts/register/$
8. ^accounts/register_success/$
9. ^articles/all/$
10. ^articles/create/$
11. ^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
12. ^articles/like/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
13. ^articles/add_comment/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$
14. ^articles/search/
15. ^articles/api/article ^(?P<resource_name>article)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
16. ^articles/api/article ^(?P<resource_name>article)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
17. ^articles/api/article ^(?P<resource_name>article)/set/(?P<pk_list>.*?)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
18. ^articles/api/article ^(?P<resource_name>article)/(?P<pk>.*?)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']

The current URL, articles/api/article, didn't match any of these.
```

Numbers 15-18 on this traceback weren't the exact statements I wrote in my urls.py file though, so I'm confused.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from django_test.api import ArticleResource`?

Comment: I did that but now I have a different ImportError. It says No module named models. I then tried adding 'models' to my settings.py file, but the command line said "no module named models". This makes no sense because I already have a models module.

Comment: You must be getting the new error message in somewhere else. You may also need to change the import in your `api.py` to `from article.models import Article`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
from tastypie.api import ArticleResource
```

For something like

```
from django_test.resources import ArticleResource
from django_test.api import ArticleResource
```

or even maybe

```
from .api ArticleResource
```

Comment: That makes no sense because I am using the TastyPie API and I want to import that. I tried both suggestions but i got the same ImportError.

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py` file, change:

```
from tastypie.api import ArticleResource
```

to

```
from django_test.api import ArticleResource
```

and in our `api.py`, change:

```
from models import Article
```

to

```
from article.models import Article
```

Comment: I think you are confused by the Django's url rerouting. You don't have a url definition for `/articles/api/article`. Can you post the contents of `urls.py` from your `article_resource` package?

Comment: `article_resource` is set to `ArticleResource`, which is inherited from the `ArticleResource` class I declared in api.py file. But I am trying to utilize the TastyPie API though.

Comment: If this fixed your (original) problem please accept it as an answer and ask the new error in a new question so that future visitors can use the information.

Comment: Actually it didn't so I just made a new post with my current problem.

Comment: But you are *not* getting any import errors now, right? This was your original problem. Your new problem is about URL rerouting.